# Something like global.asax in WPF

Tags: wpf, global-asax

I have app with lot of windows and Im just curious is there (in WPF) something like global.asax which was in ASP.NET? I just want to clean some data after somebody shutdown application with alt-f4 for example.

Thanks for answers!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Catch windows shutdown event in a wpf application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7136573/catch-windows-shutdown-event-in-a-wpf-application)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rough equivalent of `Global.asax` in WPF is `app.xaml`/`app.xaml.cs`.  You can override methods there to handle startup and shutdown.

For example, in your `app.xaml.cs`, you can add this:

```
    protected override void OnExit(ExitEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnExit(e);

        // custom exit code here
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. So when i have 30 windows, i need to put in each of them event 'application_shutdown' and redirect it to class for example?

Comment: No, the class will call your code automatically on exit.  See my edit for a sample.

Comment: One last question - how can i handle alt-f4 button pressed in app.xaml.cs?

Comment: What do you mean by "handle?"

Comment: I mean i want to know when user press alt + f4 (doesnt matter in which window) and then call method to clean data. Thing is that, i want to logout all buttons by changing their flag in base (isLogged from 1 to 0) so in OnExit im calling this method:  LogoutUser.logoutMe(); but its not cleaning data, when someone use alt-f4 to close application ;)

Comment: * all users, not all buttons... ;)

Comment: You need to debug that method - put a breakpoint on it.  Is it being called correctly?

Comment: Hmm, have no idea why, but in some windows it works (logout), but on some other doesnt..