# Execution of code after user clicks on close icon

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress

Where can I put some code, that should be executed after the user closes the window by the close-icon (the X in the upper right corner)?

If I look at MainWindow.xaml in the visualisation window, the three icons in the upper right corner are shown as silhouettes, so it looks to me like the close-event can't be reached by MainWindow.xaml/MainWindow.xaml.cs in a standard way ...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Catch windows shutdown event in a wpf application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7136573/catch-windows-shutdown-event-in-a-wpf-application)

Comment: thanks a lot! Yes, your link solved my problem.