# Application.Exit Event not invoked on system reboot

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, events

I have a WPF application that needs to save its current state every time the application exits. At the moment, I am handling the `System.Windows.Application.Exit` event to save the state of the application. However, it seems that the event is not invoked system reboots -- only ordinary shutdowns. Is this expected behavior?

This is what my application looks like.

```cs
public class MyApp : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);
        ...
        this.Exit += OnExit;
    }
    private void OnExit(object sender, ExitEventArgs e)
    {
        SaveMyApplicationState();
    }
}
```

What events can I use to be notified of a system reboot, so my application state can be saved?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Catch windows shutdown event in a wpf application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7136573/catch-windows-shutdown-event-in-a-wpf-application)

Comment: Not directly, since I am able to handle ordinary shutdown events via Application.Exit at the moment, but I'll check if it solves my problem. If so, I'll submit a PR to the docs clarifying the ambiguity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To determine when system is restarting or shutting down use the `SessionEnding` event:

> App.xaml

```
<Application ...
     SessionEnding="App_SessionEnding">
    ...
</Application>
```

> App.xaml.cs

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    void App_SessionEnding(object sender, SessionEndingCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (.../*canceling*/)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
        else
        { 
            // Processing before terminating (save current state)
            // ...               
        }
    }
}
```

For detailed information see documentation: [Application.SessionEnding Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.application.sessionending?view=netcore-3.1)

NOTE:
[Application Shutdown Changes in Windows Vista](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms700677(v=vs.85))

Comment: I looked at the docs you attached, however I don't understand how the SessionEnding event differs from Application.Exit. Quoting the documention for SessionEnding: "If SessionEnding is unhandled, or is handled without being cancelled, Shutdown is called and the Exit event is raised".

Comment: @Trympet - In documentation noted the following: `If SessionEnding is unhandled, or is handled without being cancelled, Shutdown is called and the Exit event is raised.` What the documentation not says the OS may not give enough time to application to finish executing all code inside the `Exit` event.

Comment: @Trympet - If the `SessionEnding` is handled the application still have all resources and the Operating System will wait until application is executing. The application can return `FALSE` to indicate that it should not be closed.

Comment: Ah okay, that makes sense. Thank you!